# Firebase Queries and Completion

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some trouble writing a process to allow a user to delete their Firebase account which deletes their account and all the posts that they had in their account including images. I am querying the Users posts in Firebase Database, looping through and deleting them as they come out. In the middle of this loop, I call a function passing in the image URL to delete the image from Firebase storage. The problem I am having is that I can't get an ordered result because of asynchronous stuff. I thought having completion handlers would give it some order. Should I be looking into dispatch groups? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**The start of my process with function call:**

```
         ref.deleteFirebaseDBUsersPosts(deleter) { (success) -> Void in 
            if success {
                print("The user and their info is completely gone!")
            }

        }
```

**Function that queries Firebase and loops through users posts and deletes:**

```
func deleteFirebaseDBUsersPosts(uid: String, completion:(success: Bool) -> Void) {
  let usersCurrentId = uid

    ref.child(“posts”).queryOrderedByChild("uid").queryEqualToValue("\(uid)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshot{

                print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                if let postedImg = snap.childSnapshotForPath("imageUrl").value {
                    let postImgUrl = postedImg as! String
                       self.deletingOldUsersImgsFromStorage(postImgUrl) { (success) -> Void in   
                    }
                }
                 let key = snap.key
                 ref.child(“posts”).child(key).removeValue()
                 ref.child(“users”).child(usersCurrentId).removeValue()
             }
              print("COMPLETING")
              completion(success: true)
        }

    })
}
```

**Deleting the image from Firebase Storage:**

```
 func deletingOldUsersImgsFromStorage(postImgUrl: String!, completion:(success: Bool) -> Void) {
    let deleteImgRef = ref.child(“images”).child("[imageNAME]")
    deleteImgRef.deleteWithCompletion({ (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("DEVELOPER: There was an error when trying to delete the image from Firebase Storage")
        } else {
            print("IMAGE SUCCESSFULLY DELETED FROM FIREBASE STORAGE")
        }
        completion(success: true)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dealt with a similar challenge when deleting a user and their data from Firebase. I handled it using dispatch groups to delete the user after my methods that deleted their data had completed.

```
func deleteUsersData(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {}

func deleteUsersPhotoUrl(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {}

func deleteUserFromFirebase(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {}

let group = dispatch_group_create()

dispatch_group_enter(group)
deleteUsersData { (success) in
    if success {
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
}

dispatch_group_enter(group)
deleteUsersPhotoUrl { (success) in
    if success {
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    deleteUserFromFirebase({ (success) in
        print("Completely deleted user from Firebase")
    })
}
```

Dispatch groups are great for handling situations like this where you only want to perform a task after the other tasks you specified have completed. Here is more info on how to use [dispatch groups](https://www.raywenderlich.com/79150/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-2).

Comment: Hi @nathan_falcone, thanks for your help. This does work. I was wondering if you know if I should be seeing the completion out of order? Basically, i see the completion for deleting the images from Firebase Storage printing in my console last when I called the function in the middle like you suggested. Its like its a very delayed response.

Comment: @kampbell411 the two calls will be ran asynchronously so there is a chance either one could finish first. Which is fine because of the use of dispatch groups. In the example above it doesn't matter whether the user's photo or data gets deleted first, as long as they both happen. Once both methods have completed and left their group, then dispatch notify will get called and delete the user from Firebase.

Comment: Ah I see, I get it now. Thanks again! @nathan_falcone